# Mapstruct: Returning null when trying to map a field inside an embedded object

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, mapstruct

We were given an assignment to recreate a simple version of the Twitter API in Spring using Mapstruct.

We are returning a `List<UserDto>` that should return the field `username` from the embedded object `Credentials`.

We mapped this as follows:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ProfileMapper.class, CredentialMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {

    User dtoToEntity(CreateUserDto createUserDto);

    @Mapping(target = "username", source = "credentials.username")
    List<UserDto> entitiesToDtos(List<User> users);

}
```

Our `UserDto` is specified like this:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserDto {

    private ProfileDto profile;
    private Timestamp joined;
    private String username;

}
```

Our `User` entity has an embedded object named `credentials`, where the `username` and `password` of the user are stored in String format (I know this is dumb, this is just an assignment).

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp joined;

    private boolean deleted;

    @Embedded
    private Credential credentials;

    @Embedded
    private Profile profile;
```

Long story short, when we GET all users, we should receive this (these are fake names and numbers):

```json
{
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "Chanda",
        "lastName": "Hackett",
        "email": "chandahackett@gmail.com",
        "phone": "313-574-1401"
    },
    "joined": "2021-03-17T21:15:35.289+00:00",
    "username": "chandahackett"
}
```

But instead, we receive a `null` value for username:

```json
{
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "Chanda",
        "lastName": "Hackett",
        "email": "chandahackett@gmail.com",
        "phone": "313-574-1401"
    },
    "joined": "2021-03-17T21:15:35.289+00:00",
    "username": null
}
```

I know the value username in credentials exists, as it exists in the table it is stored:

[image]

And it is accessible because other methods that call `user.getCredentials().getUsername()` return the right username.

I have tried pretty much everything. I have run `mvn clean install`, renamed variables. I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're trying to use `@Mapping` on a collection-mapping method isn't supported at the moment. You need to declare an explicit mapping from `User` to `UserDto`, and apply the annotation on it instead:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ProfileMapper.class, CredentialMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {
    User dtoToEntity(CreateUserDto createUserDto);
    @Mapping(target = "username", source = "credentials.username")
    UserDto entityToDto(User user);
    List<UserDto> entitiesToDtos(List<User> users);
}
```